# Game scene flicker when removeUnusedTexture

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2D programming. In my code i write
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
To remove unused texture. Bu when the texture is removed, the game scene flicker for a fraction of a second. How to resolve this problem. I know i am doing something wrong??..

I am using this code in creating a sprite.

```
spriteEnemyGlider = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemyGlider.png" rect:CGRectMake(0,0,79,21)];
```

And when this is removed, in console it prints

```
cocos2d: CCTextureCache: removing unused texture: enemyGlider.png
```

And the flicker occurs.

Am i doing it a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to remove unused textures during gameplay. Leave that to situations where you change scenes. Especially if it's a common texture it is counterproductive to keep removing it from memory, because cocos2d will have to load it again, which takes time.

I bet your flicker issue is coming from either the removeUnusedTexture method taking an unusually long time, or it removes the texture only to reload it a split second later.

Comment: Hi - I use this code ` [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];` Do i need to change my code??